# Starting a WPF application as hidden

Tags: wpf

I'm writing a WPF application and want it to start as a hidden window.  I've created the Window object and set its `Visibility` property to `Visibility.Hidden` before calling `Application.Run()`.  Then, I have an event handler for `Window.Loaded` that also sets the visibility to `Visibility.Hidden`.  Between the call to `Application.Run()` and the callback to `OnWindowLoaded()`, there is a black outline of the window that flashes up on the screen and then disappears.  It's like the window manager is creating a drop shadow for the window or something and then hides it immediately.

After running my project through instrumentation, I finally found that `Window.Show()` was somehow getting called.  So, I looked into the source code at http://www.dotnetframework.org/Search.aspx:

- `Application.Run()` ends up calling a private method named `Application.RunInternal()`.
- `RunInternal()` checks the visibility of the Window object that was passed in to the `Run()` method.
- If the `Visibility` property is not `Visibility.Visible`, a call to `Window.Show()` is made.

I then looked at the source for System.Windows.Window:

- `Window.Show()` sets the `Visibility` property on itself (the window) to be `Visibility.Visible`.

Based on this, I don't see how to force the window to stay hidden.  By trying to make the window invisible at startup, I'm causing the Application object to call `Window.Show()`; I don't understand why the Application object even cares about the window's visibility.  It's been a frustrating experience...   :-(

I've seen other answers that say to not call `Application.Run()` and to instead set up your own event dispatchers, but that seems like overkill for something that should be easy.  I just want the main window to stay hidden, for no "flicker" to appear at app startup, and for the window to become visible when I'm ready for it to do so (which happens later in my application logic).

Can anyone offer a suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you remove the `StartupUri` entry in `App.xaml`? If you do, the `App` class won't instantiate the window for you and show it. You can do this by yourself by overwriting the `App.OnStartup` method.

Basically, I build a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) in this `OnStartup` method and just create a window at the end of the process:

```cs
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Do your custom initialization code here

        MainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.Show();
    }
```

If you really want to omit the whole application build up process (which I wouldn't recommend, as you won't have features like the fallback to Application Resources), you can create a `Dispatcher` by yourself using this code:

```
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
var synchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(dispatcher);
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synchronizationContext);
Dispatcher.Run();
```

Comment: This works well for a sane application.  Unfortunately, the one I'm working on now has dozens of event handlers that fire at various points during application startup, each of which steps the startup forward a notch before I can show the window.  
  
So, the quick brute force approach I finally found was to start the window with `WindowState` set to `WindowState.Minimized` until I'm actually ready for the window to appear.  Then I don't have to omit the application build up process, and it works with our architecture.  
<p>
Refactoring this mess is in my future.

Answer (score 1):

The comment on this Answer finally led me to find the solution to this issue. I needed to display multiple windows on multiple screens at once, and by minimizing the window it gives me the performance I needed. Thanks.